# two python script in loop the other one have timer while other don't have

Tags: python

is it possible to run two script in python that the other one have a timer every sec in while loop while the other one don't have a timer in while loop

I already try to put it in the same while loop but the other one has been affected by the one that have a timer any idea guys

and also I forgot to say they will run infinitely

thanks in advance

Comment: You can use threading

Comment: The `threading` module may help. Run the two loops in different threads. Whether this will work depends on what those while loops do and how they interact with each other.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use multiprocessing to process two Infinite While loop:

```
from multiprocessing import process

def one():
 while True:
  print("hello world")

def two():
 while True:
  Print("lovely")
  time.sleep(2)

if __name__=='__main__':
 f=Process(target=one)
 f.start()

 k=Process(target=two)
 k.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple python program where two loops run parallel.

First function prints 1 to 50 in first 10 second and then other function gets activated and runs after 10 second

```
import threading
import time

print("The other process will run after 10 sec")
def threadFunc():
    time.sleep(10)
    
    j = 0
    
    while j < 50:
        print("J is at {}".format(j))
        
        j += 1
        
        time.sleep(1.5) 
        
thread = threading.Thread(target=threadFunc)

thread.start()

i = 0

while i < 50:
    print('I variable is now at {}'.format(i))
    
    i += 1
    
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I will  try it and i just new in python so thank you very much

Comment: Yeah sure. I will be glad if this code will help you <3